# HOW to finalize my vb.net and work without error in MS access database destination

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have three paths/destinations in my vb.net project, i want to make it work in all computers i add my program in it.

my database destination was

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sh\Desktop\TEST\Database.accdb
```

after i compiled and build the project, it works 
BUT after i copy the program in another computer it doesnt work.

*then i changed my destination to...*

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb"
```

*also i tried*

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\Database.accdb"
```

**BUT THEY ARE NOT WORKING**

my other destination for open my DGV in PDF "im using iTexSharp"

```
 Dim fontArialBold As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)

 Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Sha\Desktop\"
```

---

**also can the program work in a computer doesn't have VB.net or MS access?**

Comment: Why would you put the database for your application in a folder on the desktop?  That is just a really, really bad decision.  So many people deliberately make things harder for themselves and then wonder why things are hard. Add the database file to your project, which you should have done in the first place.  You can then use the second option you showed and it will just work.  The only extra step you may want to perform is setting the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the database to `Copy if Newer` to prevent your test data being lost every time you build.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney my database is in my project folder already......

Comment: Then why does your connection string refer to a folder on the desktop? Here's how it should work. You add your data file to your project. When you build, VS copies the data file to the output folder with your EXE. Using "|DataDirectory|" in your connection string will just work, resolving to the same folder as your EXE at run time while debugging. It will continue to resolve to the same folder as the EXE if you use XCOPY deployment. If you use ClickOnce, the data file will be placed in a dedicated folder and the connection string will continue to just work.

Comment: If you have a compelling reason to store the data file in a location other than the default then you should generally set `Copy to Output Folder` to `Never Copy` and then create your own copy of the file in the appropriate location. If that location can't be known at design time then you can't hard-code a connection string at design time. You either need the user to edit the config file after deployment or you need code to resolve the file location at run time. How you write that code depends on what possible locations the file might be stored in.

Comment: Of course you can run your application a machine without VB.NET installed. It's a .NET app though, so it requires the appropriate version of the .NET Framework installed. You can also run it without Access installed but, if you use an ACCDB file, then you do need ACE installed. That will be installed with Office or you can do a standalone install. If you use an MDB file instead then the database engine is basically part of Windows.

Comment: ok. now should i transfer my database to specific folder in my project as (debug or bin..)?

Comment: would you please give me a link that explains how to make the project ready to use